# google pie chart in wordpress

Tags: javascript

i create html elements dynamically using jquery and i draw chart using google chart but i can't see the pie chart. i have attached the code below

```
$("#parent").append(response.val); - for creating div element
                            
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
```

i have attached the library in function.php as below

```
wp_enqueue_script('charts',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/gstatic/loader.js',array('jquery'));
```

I can't find out the error

Comment: There's not enough information in the question. What is not working? Is loader.js being loaded by the browser? Where is your JavasScript from? What is `response`? What is `drawChart1`?

Answer (score 0):

with the help of the **[WordPress chart plugin - Graphina Pro](https://iqonic.design/product/wordpress-plugins/graphina-pro-elementor-dynamic-charts-graphs-datatables/)**, you can implement a pie chart easily. This WordPress charts and graphs plugin allows many customizations. Allow choosing from modern fonts and color palettes to edit the graph and chart template.

Comment: That may be true, but it should be possible to get Google Charts working too.